# Is there a way to insert some values(from one form) into two different tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to insert the **names** (First name and Last name) details of a user registering into **[first name]** and **[last name]** column of a **user_details table**. Consequently, the **email** and **password** to their respective columns of a **snm_users table**

How can I possibly achieve this in **Codeigniter**?

Here is snippet of my input form:

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

And here is the model to handle database:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {
    public function register ($enc_password){
        $data = array(
            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $enc_password
        );
        //insert user to database
        return $this->db->insert('snm_users', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should call both models in controller and then save accordingly. Or you may make a helper function in which you can call both models and save data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are new to CodeIgniter. Better do some research to get a basic idea of how the MVC (Model View Controller) really works. I will give you a basic idea: `VIEW` is where you use the HTML, like displaying the form, and any output stuff, etc. `MODEL` is where you write the code for db interactions. Like INSERTIONS, UPDATIONS, SELECT queries, etc. And `CONTROLLER` is where you do you business logic, validations, etc.

In the code snippet you posted above, you are using the data submitted from the form directly inside your MODEL. Which is kind of not the best approach. Accept it (from `$this->input->post()` inside your CONTROLLER, and then do the validations and pass it to the MODEL.

And back to your question, you want to insert the `first_name` and `last_name` in `user_details_table` and `email` and `password` in another table (`snm_users_table`)

For this, first do the insertion in your main table. I believe its `snm_users_table`. And I assume that you have a primarykey named `user_id` or something to identify each record. So, once you insert in this main User table, you can get the `last_insert_id`(id of this newly inserted row) using this function: `$this->db->insert_id()`

Now, you can use this `user_id` returned by the above function to insert the other details on your second table, which is `user_details_table`.

You can use TRANSACTIONS during these insertions, so that you won't end up inserting a record in one table and no record in the other table, in case of any errors! Because TRANSACTIONS would help you to rollback the changes in case of any problems!

Read more here:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Hope this will give you an idea. :)